# In edittext hint need to scroll horizontally

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my app i have Edit text with fixed size but hint size is more than edit text so hint is not displayed fully.I want to display hint fully by scrolling horizontally but i don't have any idea how to do this.

If reduce the size of hint font it will help but i don't want to reduce font size.

Following is the example code which i use.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/test_etx"
    android:hint="@string/hint"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bt3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etx"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etx"
    android:maxLength="10"
    />
```

Comment: try adding `android:scrollbars="horizontal"`.

Comment: or you can wrap the edittext inside a horizontal scroll view.

Comment: i try that one also but hint is not scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your EditText width match_parent. Put that inside a horizontal scroll view. I tried and it works. If you want fixed width, give fixed width to your horizontal scroll view. Like this :

```
<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/bt3"
                      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                      android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                      android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
                      android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etx"
                      android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etx">

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:singleLine="true"
android:id="@+id/test_etx"
android:hint="@string/hint"
android:maxLength="10"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: it works in app also but border of edit text is not properly.Like if text is scroll to left side right border is not displayed.if scroll to right left is not displayed.

Comment: if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First you can add a scroll in editText then put text in edit Text with grey font color instead of hint and then put a `OnClickListener` on the editText. If input text matches hint then set it to "" else process the data.

Make two arrays of EditText id and its corresponding hint in values res. Then fetch both arrays using `getResource()`. 
Use

```
String str = view.getResources().getResourceName(id);
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(":id/") + 4);
```

to get view id.

match hint from stored array's hint to input text. I think it will be generalised for all the layouts. Hope it helped.

Comment: in one layout i have multiple edit text views if i change one edittext i need to change every edittext.

Comment: So every layout have long hints??

Comment: 2 r 3 for one layout.